# Why Shir HaMaalos on Erev Tisha B'Av?

Tags: tisha-bav, bentching

The [custom](https://crownheights.info/notices/7513/halachos-and-minhogim-for-tishaa-bav/) is some places [seems](https://anash.org/halacha-guide-tisha-bav/) to be to say Shir Hamaalos before bentching for the seuda mafsekes on Erev Tisha B'Av. Although we [normally](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Zimmun#Shir_HaMaalot) say Shir Hamaalos for bentching whenever we don't say Tachanun - which would seem to include Erev Tisha B'av - is the common custom to say Al Naaros Bavel for Erev Tisha B'Av (which is the *most* *appropriate* time to say the Tehillim focused on the destruction) or Shir HaMaalos?

Comment: Seems to be a chabad custom. I’m not sure how many others follow this.

Comment: I've never seen nor heard of this. It's rather shocking in fact to think anyone would do this.

Answer (score 3):

Rav Chaim Kanievsky is [quoted](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjlwLWUuvXqAhXfoHIEHeOmAmYQFjACegQIAxAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbeinenu.com%2Fsystem%2Ffiles%2Falonim%2F02_44_80.pdf%3Fdownload%3D1&usg=AOvVaw0mhjOR1LpbXUHvR-HSrL46) as saying you should say Al Naharos on Erev Tisha B'av since that is most appropriate.

[image]